# Android emulator has no network connectivity on Linux

Tags: android, linux, android-emulator

I had this problem for weeks.  I tried the common suggestions of running it via `emulator -avd namehere -dns-server 8.8.8.8` and turning off other network adapters but to no avail.

Networking is fine in Windows but I had no such luck with either Manjaro or Ubuntu.

Any ideas why this would not work in a Linux dev machine? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it turns out to NOT be a connectivity issue (I remember being able to ping `10.0.2.2` using `adb shell`).

It has something to do with a GPU driver error, since I'm always getting this error when I start the emulator.  So it's most likely the browser not rendering the page, giving the illusion that there's no connectivity.

> "Some users have experienced emulator stability issues with this driver version."

Came close to joining the Windows army.  In case someone runs into a similar problem, with the primary symptom being the page really not loading (as opposed to it saying "There is no Internet connection").

[image: pages not loading]

Start the emulator with the `-gpu off` switch.  It makes the difference in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. People told me to do complicated tasks, here's what worked for me:

Open emulator and just turn on data and in wifi settings connect to wifi named Android.

Comment: No it doesn't work for me.  Are you on Linux as well?

Comment: Yeah. Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I'm on 17.04 with a Marshmallow x86 emulator.  I dunno how much that would make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

i solved by modifying nameserver

gedit /etc/resolv.conf

nameserver 8.8.8.8

nameserver fe80::1%eth0

nameserver 8.8.4.4